# Changing behaviour of stats::lag when loading dplyr package

Tags: r, dplyr

I am having trouble with the `stats::lag` function when using the
`dplyr` package. Specifically, I get different results from the lag
function before and after loading `dplyr`.

For example, here is a sample time series. If I calculate the lag with
`k = -1`, the lagged series starts in 1971.

```
data <- ts(1:10, start = 1970, frequency = 1)
lag1 <- stats::lag(data, k = -1)
start(lag1)[1]

## [1] 1971
```

Now, if I load `dplyr`, the same call yields a lagged series starting in
1970.

```
library(dplyr)

## 
## Attaching package: 'dplyr'
## 
## The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
## 
##     filter
## 
## The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
## 
##     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

lag2 <- stats::lag(data, k = -1)
start(lag2)[1]

## [1] 1970

start(lag1)[1] == start(lag2)[1]

## [1] FALSE
```

Given the warnings when loading `dplyr`, my guess is that this has to do
with Environments. But, detaching `dplyr` doesn't seem to help.

```
detach("package:dplyr", unload = TRUE, character.only = TRUE)
lag3 <- stats::lag(data, k = -1)
start(lag3)[1]

## [1] 1970

start(lag1)[1] == start(lag3)[1]

## [1] FALSE
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. My only solution so far is to
restart the R session between calculating `lag1` and `lag2`.

Here's my session:

```
##  setting  value                       
##  version  R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
##  system   i386, mingw32               
##  ui       RTerm                       
##  language (EN)                        
##  collate  English_Canada.1252         
##  tz       America/New_York            
## 
##  package    * version  date       source        
##  assertthat   0.1      2013-12-06 CRAN (R 3.2.0)
##  bitops       1.0-6    2013-08-17 CRAN (R 3.2.0)
##  DBI          0.3.1    2014-09-24 CRAN (R 3.2.0)
##  devtools     1.8.0    2015-05-09 CRAN (R 3.2.0)
##  digest       0.6.8    2014-12-31 CRAN (R 3.2.0)
##  dplyr        0.4.1    2015-01-14 CRAN (R 3.2.0)
##  evaluate     0.7      2015-04-21 CRAN (R 3.2.0)
##  formatR      1.2      2015-04-21 CRAN (R 3.2.0)
##  git2r        0.10.1   2015-05-07 CRAN (R 3.2.0)
##  htmltools    0.2.6    2014-09-08 CRAN (R 3.2.0)
##  httr       * 0.6.1    2015-01-01 CRAN (R 3.2.0)
##  knitr        1.10.5   2015-05-06 CRAN (R 3.2.0)
##  magrittr     1.5      2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.2.0)
##  memoise      0.2.1    2014-04-22 CRAN (R 3.2.0)
##  Rcpp         0.11.6   2015-05-01 CRAN (R 3.2.0)
##  RCurl        1.95-4.6 2015-04-24 CRAN (R 3.2.0)
##  rmarkdown    0.6.1    2015-05-07 CRAN (R 3.2.0)
##  rversions    1.0.0    2015-04-22 CRAN (R 3.2.0)
##  stringi      0.4-1    2014-12-14 CRAN (R 3.2.0)
##  stringr      1.0.0    2015-04-30 CRAN (R 3.2.0)
##  XML          3.98-1.1 2013-06-20 CRAN (R 3.2.0)
##  yaml         2.1.13   2014-06-12 CRAN (R 3.2.0)
```

I've also tried `unloadNamespace`, as suggested by @BondedDust:

```
unloadNamespace("dplyr")  
lag4 <- stats::lag(data, k = -1)  

## Warning: namespace 'dplyr' is not available and has been replaced  
## by .GlobalEnv when processing object 'sep'  

start(lag4)[1]  

## [1] 1970  

start(lag1)[1] == start(lag4)[1]  

## [1] FALSE
```

Comment: `detach` may not be completely effective. I generally use `unloadNamespace`.  (But I just tried and it was ineffective.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I still get `start = 1970` though. But, have added this option to the question above.

Comment: Yeah. Agree this is puzzling. `getAnywhere(lag.default)` with dply loaded retruns: `2 differing objects matching ‘lag.default’ were found
in the following places
  registered S3 method for lag from namespace dplyr
  namespace:dplyr
  namespace:stats
Use [] to view one of them`. Seems dplyr is overwriting lag.default an not giving a warning about it.

Comment: Using the comment facility to send message to @hadley

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The dplyr package is effectively overwriting 'lag'. The dispatch mechanism is not finding `lag` because there really is no function by that name, just two copies of `lag.default`, one in 'stats' and one in 'dplyr' and the 'dplyr' copy is being found first. You can force the stats version to be found with the use of the `:::`-mechanism:

```
> lag2 <- stats::lag.default(data, k = -1)
Error: 'lag.default' is not an exported object from 'namespace:stats'

> lag2 <- stats:::lag.default(data, k = -1)
> stats::start(lag2)[1]
[1] 1971
```

The `dplyr:::lag.default` does not use the time-series specific functions. I'm not able to explain why unloadNamespace fails to remove the function's definition but it is still there:

```
> unloadNamespace("dplyr")
> getAnywhere(lag.default)
2 differing objects matching ‘lag.default’ were found
in the following places
  registered S3 method for lag from namespace dplyr
  namespace:stats
Use [] to view one of them
```

Further weirdness: After unloading the `dply`-namespace I see this:

```
> environment(getAnywhere(lag.default)[1])
<environment: namespace:dplyr>
> environment(getAnywhere(lag.default)[2])
<environment: namespace:dplyr>
> environment(getAnywhere(lag.default)[3])
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

(And then restarting and loading dplyr, I see the same apparent double-entry.)

There's also something weird about the help page for `dplyr::lag`:

```
> help(lag,pac=dplyr)
No documentation for ‘lag’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??lag’
> help(`lag`,pac=`dplyr`)
No documentation for ‘lag’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??lag’
> help(`lag.default`,pac=`dplyr`)  # This finally succeeds!
```

Looking at github (after determining that I had the latest version of dplyr on CRAN), I see that this was an issue for the `R CMD check` process: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/commit/f8a46e030b7b899900f2091f41071619d0a46288 . Apparently `lag.default` will not be over-written in future versions, but `lag` will mask the stats-version. I wonder what happens to `lag.zoo` and `lag.zooreg`. Maybe it will also announce that over-writing or masking when the package is loaded?

Comment: That does it! Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: FYI, I recently ran into this problem with the `zoo` package.  Interestingly, when I load `dplyr` after `zoo` the `lag.zoo` appears to be masked though there is NO warning.  42-'s work around is still valid, i.e. `zoo:::lag.zoo(x, n)`.