# Weird behaviour of lag function of dplyr inside mutate

Tags: r, dplyr, lag

I guess it is correlated to that story : [Changing behaviour of stats::lag when loading dplyr package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30466740/changing-behaviour-of-statslag-when-loading-dplyr-package) , but I've found some weird behaviour of `lag` function when I try to use the `default =` option.

Check the simple commands below

```
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame(mtcars)

df %>% mutate(lag_cyl = lag(cyl))
## it works with NA in first value (as expected)

df %>% mutate(lag_cyl = lag(cyl, default = 999))
## it works with a given value as default

df %>% mutate(lag_cyl = lag(cyl, default = cyl[1]))
## it DOESN'T WORK with the first value of the column as default

df %>% mutate(lag_cyl = dplyr::lag(cyl, default = cyl[1]))
## it works when specifying dplyr::

val = df$cyl[1]
df %>% mutate(lag_cyl = lag(cyl, default = val))
## it works when I assign the first value of the column to a variable name
```

Is it just a conflict between the `stats` and `dplyr` packages?

Comment: Bizarrely, the following works as well:

    `df %>% mutate(lag_cyl = stats::lag(cyl, default = cyl[1]))`

Comment: @crazybilly It doesn't return an error, indeed, but does it shift the `cyl` values by one position in the new `lag_cyl` column?

Comment: Oh, you're right--it doesn't return the desired effect. That said, it's not returning the same error, so at least we know that's not what's happening when you leave the "dplyr::" part off.

Comment: This looks similar to this (closed) [github issue](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1411) - maybe try the dev version?

Comment: This appears to work in version 0.7.4, I suggest this question be closed.

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm that `df %>% mutate(lag_cyl = lag(cyl, default = cyl[1]))` works in dplyr version 0.8.0.1.

If it worked when specifying `dplyr::lag` it suggests that another library was masking the function. Hmisc has a function called lag, and you may have loaded this library (or another one with a lag function) after loading dplyr.

Comment: I think this is what happened in my case too. Thank you!!