# Avoiding function name conflicts in R

Tags: r, namespaces, dplyr

I recently ran into a situation in which existing R code broke due the introduction of the `dplyr` library.  Specifically, the `lag` function from the stats package, is being replaced by `dplyr::lag`.  The problem is previously documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30466740/changing-behaviour-of-statslag-when-loading-dplyr-package), however no work around is provided.  Research into R namespaces and environments leads to 2 possible solutions, neither very robust in my opinion:

1. Make sure that `package:stats` appears first in the `search()` path so that `lag` resolves as the function in the stats package.
2. Change all references of `lag` in my code to `stats::lag`

My question is whether either of these other solutions are possible:

1. Loading the `dplyr` package in a way to force it to be in a "private" namespace in which its objects can only be accessed through the `::` operator.
2. A directive at library loading to force `lag` to resolve as `stats::lag`. This could be done either by removing `dplyr::lag` or overriding the search path (similar to the C++ *using namespace::function* directive.)

Comment: I believe that `Change all references of lag in my code to stats::lag` is more or less the official recommendation, hence my snark [here](https://twitter.com/joranelias/status/676879776502579200)

Comment: A very easy way to make sure `lag` refers to `stats::lag` is to simply do `lag <- stats::lag`.  The Global Environment is earlier on the search path than package namespaces.

Comment: Thanks, @Gregor.  I tried something like that, but was making it more difficult than it is and got the syntax wrong.  Still seems like there should be something more robust than that, but I will take that as a fallback solution.

Comment: @Gregor brilliant suggestion, especially since (I believe) it would work nicely with the respective entry in .Rprofile.

Answer (score 5):

you should consider `library(conflicted)` as it's designed for exactly this problem.
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/conflicted/index.html

putting `conflicted::conflict_prefer(name = "lag", winner = "stats")` after you load your packages ensures that anytime the function `lag()` is called in your script, it will use the stats function by default.