# Retain zoo class after lapply

Tags: r, lapply, zoo

Suppose I have the following `zoo` object that contains stock prices.

```
library('PerformanceAnalytics')
library('magrittr')

x.zoo <- structure(c(194.74, 194.74, 186.55, 190.65, 198.83, 12.4, 12.4, 
12.4, 12.4, 12.4, 12333.94, 12333.94, 12401.71, 12266.17, 12333.94
), .Dim = c(5L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(c("27", "28", "29", "30", 
"31"), c("BBY", "BHY", "COST")), index = structure(c(5478, 5479, 
5480, 5481, 5482), class = "Date"), class = c("zooreg", "zoo"
), frequency = 1)
```

I want to calculate returns using `Return.calculate` from `PerformanceAnalytics` package as follow:

```
Return.calculate(x.zoo)
```

this worked fine with me in the past, but for some reasons it starts giving me the following error:

> Error in `[.xts`(x, seq_len(xlen - n)) : subscript out of bounds

Then I used the following to run the `Return.calculate` function over the columns of `x.zoo`

```
x.zoo  %>% lapply(., Return.calculate) # %>% operator is from dplyr package
```

This works fine, however, it returns an object of a class `list` rather than `zoo`
as follow:

```
x.zoo  %>% lapply(., Return.calculate)  %>% class
[1] "list"
```

Question is how to retain `zoo` class after apply?

UPDATE with `SessionInfo()`

```
R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.4 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] quantmod_0.4-5                TTR_0.23-1                    extrafont_0.17               
 [4] fontcm_1.1                    car_2.1-0                     dplyr_0.4.3                  
 [7] tidyr_0.3.1                   stringr_1.0.0                 readxl_0.1.1                 
[10] haven_0.2.0                   readr_0.2.2                   aod_1.3                      
[13] fUnitRoots_3010.78            fBasics_3011.87               timeSeries_3022.101.2        
[16] timeDate_3012.100             corrplot_0.73                 Hmisc_3.17-0                 
[19] Formula_1.2-1                 survival_2.38-3               lattice_0.20-33              
[22] reshape2_1.4.1                scales_0.3.0                  psych_1.5.8                  
[25] stargazer_5.2                 plyr_1.8.3                    openxlsx_3.0.0               
[28] qpcR_1.4-0                    Matrix_1.2-4                  robustbase_0.92-5            
[31] rgl_0.95.1429                 minpack.lm_1.2-0              tikzDevice_0.9               
[34] vars_1.5-2                    lmtest_0.9-34                 urca_1.2-8                   
[37] strucchange_1.5-1             sandwich_2.3-4                MASS_7.3-45                  
[40] tseries_0.10-34               ggfortify_0.1.0               ggplot2_2.1.0                
[43] proto_0.3-10                  packrat_0.4.6-1               PerformanceAnalytics_1.4.3541
[46] xts_0.9-7                     zoo_1.7-12                    xtable_1.8-0                 
[49] xlsx_0.5.7                    xlsxjars_0.6.1                gdata_2.17.0                 
[52] rJava_0.9-7                   XLConnect_0.2-11              XLConnectJars_0.2-9          

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] splines_3.2.4       gtools_3.5.0        assertthat_0.1      latticeExtra_0.6-26
 [5] Rttf2pt1_1.3.3      quantreg_5.19       quadprog_1.5-5      extrafontdb_1.0    
 [9] RColorBrewer_1.1-2  minqa_1.2.4         colorspace_1.2-6    SparseM_1.7        
[13] MatrixModels_0.4-1  lme4_1.1-10         mgcv_1.8-12         nnet_7.3-12        
[17] pbkrtest_0.4-4      mnormt_1.5-3        magrittr_1.5        nlme_3.1-125       
[21] foreign_0.8-66      tools_3.2.4         munsell_0.4.2       cluster_2.0.3      
[25] nloptr_1.0.4        filehash_2.3        gtable_0.1.2        DBI_0.3.1          
[29] R6_2.1.1            gridExtra_2.0.0     stringi_1.0-1       parallel_3.2.4     
[33] Rcpp_0.12.2         rpart_4.1-10        acepack_1.3-3.3     DEoptimR_1.0-4
```

Comment: that's a terrible package name

Comment: lapply returns a list of zoo objects, so you might want to try `x.zoo  %>% lapply(Return.calculate) %>% lapply(class)`. and `Return.calculate(x.zoo)` works fine for me

Comment: @rawr tried `Return.calculate(x.zoo)` again but still doesn't work, even after specifying the package name.

Comment: I don't know then. maybe add your `sessionInfo()`

Comment: @rawr I updated the question with `sessionInfo()`

Comment: hm, I'm using the same versions as you. you're only using the `x.zoo` in your question and not another one, right? do you still get the error in a new r session with only the code and packages in your question?

Comment: @rawr I started a new session as you advised and it worked very well. I required the packages one by one, and once I require `dplyr`, it gives the above error. I will post another question for this.

Comment: yes there is a conflict between `stats::lag` and `dplyr::lag` when you load dplyr

Comment: @rawr So how do I overcome this conflict?

Comment: I'm not sure. you can reassign lag, `lag <- stats::lag` after you load dplyr, but really this is the fault of the author @hadley also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30466740/changing-behaviour-of-statslag-when-loading-dplyr-package) with a similar issue

Comment: It is also possible to overwrite `lag` in dplyr:  `dplyr <- as.environment("package:dplyr");
unlockBinding("lag", dplyr);
dplyr$lag <- stats::lag`

Comment: If loading dplyr breaks code _inside_ another package, the bug in that package (usually because the namespace specification is incorrect), not dplyr.